# how to call function inside a function

Tags: php

There is an error : Call to undefined function tim() 
How can I solve this issue?

```
public function SelectEmailLimit(){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT fname, mname, lname, created_at FROM ms_membership ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4");

    $stmt->execute();
    $row =array();
    $stmt->bind_result($fname, $mname, $lname,$created);// can write any name to bind the result shouldnot be same as table row name
     while ($stmt->fetch())
      {
       $create =tim($created);

        $row[] = array(

                    'fname' => $fname,
                    'mname' => $mname,
                    'lname' => $lname,
                    'created' => $create
                    );

       }

    function tim($created){
      return me;
    }
    $stmt->close();
     return $row;


    }
```

Comment: define `tim` function outside of `SelectEmailLimit`

Comment: create `tim` function outside `SelectEmailLimit`. Also `me` is undefined in `tim`

Comment: We can't guess from this piece of code, what is me? so nobody can tell you why it is undefined.

Comment: You cannot define a function inside a function in PHP like that. At best, but I strongly discourage that, you can store a function reference in a variable and call that...

Comment: If you start programming like that, you're ready to learn about closures ;-)

Answer (score 4):

PHP doesn't have scope for functions, so "functions within functions" aren't "a thing". What happens is that `function tim` will be dynamically defined ***globally*** when that line of code is first hit. That means:

1. You cannot call it before you define it.
2. If you call `SelectEmailLimit` twice, PHP will attempt to define the function twice, which will result in an error.

The only thing PHP has akin to what you want are anonymous functions:

```
$tim = function ($created) { return me; };

...

$create = $tim($created);
```

These you obviously also need to define before you call.